ACER ASPIRE ES1-521: Can't boot from UEFI USB
Ubuntu Live USB isn't found on UEFI mode.
When Changing Bios to Legacy mode the USB is booted.

The bootable ubuntu stick must be GPT partition FAT32 format, not MBR partition. Use Rufus to create the GPT FAT32 bootable stick with the Ubuntu iso.
